# Extending prototypejs toggle() for effects

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, effects, scriptaculous, fbjs

Is there a way to extend the toggle method in prorotypejs to allow for injection of an effect function, eg, scriptaculous effects or [FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS)

Comment: is this so you could do - for example - an Effect.Fade / Effect.Appear toggle ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to this that I wrote for the Effect.SlideDown/Up, should work for Fade/Appear. jQuery provides a slideToggle function, which has similar syntax... this could be written better, but for lack of time:

```
<script>
function slideToggle(id,time) {

    toggle = typeof(toggle)=='undefined' ? true : toggle;

    if (toggle) {
        Effect.SlideDown(id, { duration: time });
        toggle = false;
    }
    else {
        Effect.SlideUp(id, { duration: time });
        toggle = true;
    }
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:slideToggle('hidden',0.5); return false;">Click to Toggle</a>

<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
<div>Hey Yourself!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question